# Sourceannotations.h ? C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

What is this errormessage in Visual Studio 2008

```
Error 1 error C2144: syntax error : '__w64 unsigned int' should be preceded by ';' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h 19 Steg2_Labs
```

I don't have any headerfiles made myself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon somewhere before the "integral type" declaration.

Since you say there aren't any other libraries included (written by you) than it must be in the current file and usualy the statement directly before the error line number.

Comment: Enable all the characters and check if there are any other characters in the end of the line above it. In my case there was a non-printable character as I copied it from a website.

Comment: FWIW, my stray character was at the very top of the file.

Answer (score 17):

Faced the same problem. **It was due to a stray character** 'F'. When pressing Ctrl + F to find something, the Ctrl somehow wasn't detected and instead, an 'F' was added at the top of the file.

Diff with your previous version and remove any stray characters!

Comment: did exactly the same thing, was scratching my head for ages!

Answer (score 3):

missing a semicolon at the end of the code

Answer (score 1):

I have just gotten the very same compiling-error, in the very same file and line. And nothing to do with missing semicolons.

I just cleaned the projects, closed the environment, and manually deleted, the *.sdf and *.pdb files.

After that, reopened the project and recompiled fine. It seemed to be some kind of data-corruption which leaded to incorrect precompiled header generation, and eventually to that specific error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a missing semicolon in your code. If you post your code, it is easier to say what is wrong.

Comment: Ok it works now, I was in the headerannotations.h file but I didn't change anything, strange...

Comment: Really strange. Are you sure you changed nothing in your source code as well?

Comment: so what did u do do get it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you played with the project configuration - platform, optimizations, align, etc.? Looks like some clash of configuration options (that is if you haven't written any code to cause this)