# visual c++ fstream error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, csv, fstream

first of all I'm a hardware programmer (HDL, uC programming) and was asked by my boss a couple of days ago to create an Interface in visual C++ to control a uC. I never used visual C++ before and my software programming skills are intermediate at best. However, I only have till Tuesday to get the interface to work, therefore I had to look for examples and do the same, due to the time frame I have. So please excuse me if I ask any obvious and stupid questions.

In my code, I have to move values stored in an array to a CSV file. So I have to separate my values using commas... 
However, in order to create a CSV file, I have to use fstream (as far as I understood from what I've read so far).
Whenever I use

```
#include <fstream>
```

I get a huge amount of errors such as:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(244): error C3083: 'vc_attributes': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(244): error C2039: 'YesNoMaybe' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
```

Here is the rest of my code related to fstream:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::IO::Ports;
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

      std::ofstream myfile;
            myfile.open("Data.txt");
            //find available ports
            private: void findports(void){
                         array<Object^>^ objectArray = SerialPort::GetPortNames();
                         this->comboBox4->Items->AddRange( objectArray );
                         array<String ^> ^ h = gcnew array<String ^>(24);
                         for(int i=0; i<=23; i++){
                             h[i]= String::Concat(i.ToString());
                         }
                         this->comboBox1->Items->AddRange( h );
                          array<String ^> ^ m = gcnew array<String ^>(60);
                         for(int i=0; i<=59; i++){
                             m[i]= String::Concat(i.ToString());
                         }
                         this->comboBox3->Items->AddRange( m );
                          array<String ^> ^ s = gcnew array<String ^>(24);
                         for(int i=0; i<=23; i++){
                             s[i]= String::Concat(i.ToString());
                         }
                         this->comboBox5->Items->AddRange( s );
                          array<String ^> ^ d = gcnew array<String ^>(366);
                         for(int i=0; i<=365; i++){
                             d[i]= String::Concat(i.ToString());
                         }
                         this->comboBox2->Items->AddRange( d);
                     }








        private: System::Void label1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 }
        private: System::Void label2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 }
    private: System::Void label4_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void label5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void label6_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                 if((this->comboBox4->Text == String::Empty)||(this->textBox1->Text == String::Empty)||(this->textBox2->Text == String::Empty)){
                     this->textBox1->Text="missing port settings";
                     this->textBox2->Text="missing port settings";
                 }
                 else{ // start assigning
                     try{ // first make sure port isn't busy/open
                         if(!this->serialPort1->IsOpen){
                             // select the port whose name is in comboBox4 (select port)
                             this->serialPort1->PortName=this->comboBox4->Text;
                             //open the port
                             this->serialPort1->Open();


                             // sending
                             String^ name_ = this->serialPort1->PortName;
                             String^ sampling_period_ = this->comboBox5->Text;

                             String^ days_ = this->comboBox2->Text;

                             String^ hours_ = this->comboBox3->Text;

                             String^ minutes_ = this->comboBox1->Text;

                             String^ start_ = this->textBox1->Text;

                             String^ end_ = this->textBox2->Text;

                             //send data to setup timer on the microcontroller
                             this->serialPort1->WriteLine(sampling_period_);
                             this->serialPort1->WriteLine(days_);
                             this->serialPort1->WriteLine(hours_);
                             this->serialPort1->WriteLine(minutes_);
                             // send slave addresses
                             this->serialPort1->WriteLine(start_);
                             this->serialPort1->WriteLine(end_);


                             // receiving
                             int rec[100][8];
                             for (int i=0;i<sizeof(rec[0]);i++){
                                 for (int j=0;j<sizeof(rec);j++){
                                     rec[i][j]=int::Parse(this->serialPort1->ReadLine());
                                 }
                             }
                             myfile<<"ADC1"<<","<<"ADC2"<<","<<"ADC3"<<","<<"ADC4"<<","<<"ADC5"<<","<<"ADC6"<<","<<"ADC7"<<","<<"ADC8"<<endl;
                             for (int i=0;i<sizeof(rec[0]);i++){
                                 for (int j=0;j<sizeof(rec);j++){
                                     myfile<<rec[i][j]<<",";
                                 }
                                 myfile<<endl;
                             }



                         }
                         else{
                             this->textBox1->Text="Warning: port is busy or isn't open";
                             this->textBox2->Text="Warning: port is busy or isn't open";
                         }
                     }
                        catch(UnauthorizedAccessException^){
                            this->textBox1->Text="Unauthorized access";
                            this->textBox2->Text="Unauthorized access";
                        }
                     }

             }
    private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void label7_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             }
    private: System::Void label8_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    };
    }
```

I hope to get some help or at least any useful information in here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error messages don't look like they have anything to do with the code presented here. Please post real code, the shortest you can come up with, that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You're not showing enough...  Are you able to post more of your code?  Particularly any of your own includes.  If you are getting errors in the in-built header files, it could mean you're missing a semi-colon in your own, or not closing an open `#if????` clause with the corresponding `#endif`.

Comment: Don't post more. Post different.

Comment: wrt the error you put in - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176877/sourceannotations-h-c the implication is that there is a missing semi-colon somewhere?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit but so many bosses like him :(

Comment: You appear to be mixing global functions, class definitions, free statements and the entirely different language C++/CLI. Really, at this point, you have no hope of getting this done for Tuesday. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("Data.txt");
```

That last line is a statement, which can only occur inside a function, not at namespace scope (i.e. outside any function body) as you've written it.

```
44): error C3083: 'vc_attributes': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(244): error C2039: 'YesNoMaybe' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
```

This error cannot possibly come from the code you showed, which doesn't mention `vc_attribtues` or `YesNoMaybe`.  You'll get better answers if you simplify your code to the minimum necessary to show the problem, and post the error that matches the code.

I'm not sure what you expect to get from `sizeof(rec)` but it's probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I will edit my first post by adding more about the code.

Comment: Good point... It looks as if the `#include` may be inside a function, or the rest of the code is outside a function.

Comment: @user1816731: SO is a Q&A -- seems like you'd be better off in a chatroom. Try IRC!

Comment: @Jonathan: You are right I got it. I was using include inside a function. Finally I got rid of those ugly errors. Thanks a lot people... and Lightness